# IFTTT to send me a message using mobile messaging

Tags: if-this-then-that, instant-messaging

Using IFTTT, I want to do something like

```
If it becomes 4:38

then send me "hello" to my phone using some mobile messaging service
```

The messaging app can be just anything, anything, unless it takes more than 3 seconds to send a single message.

SMS turned out to be not what I want because the messages should be able to be seen by other people through internet.  I need a message service like Google Hangouts, in which people can chat online, rather than SMS which can't be accessed by PC via online.

Also, I live in GMT9. How should I set the time part in the if part?

Comment: I think you're going to need to be clearer as to exactly what you want. You say you want it to be sent by SMS, but then you say you don't. What service do you want the message sent to?

Comment: @phantom42 I mean I need message services like google hangout at which people can chat online, rather than SMS which can't be accessed by PC via online.

Comment: If SMS doesn't work for you, what have you already tried? Obviously you can use the time/date channel for your trigger, but you need to select one of their available channels to send the message too. Go to http://ifttt.com/channels and see which one will suit you best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple [IFTTT recipes](https://ifttt.com/recipes?channel=date_and_time&t=3&type=triggers) that can let you post a message via external services like Twitter, FB, email. These services can be configured to reach your mobile as well as be saved at a centralized site for others as well to see.